# Open text file in Numbers when it is space delimited, but some fields are strings in quotes with spaces

Tags: numbers

I have a log file I'd like to open in Numbers to make sifting through it a lot easier.  The problem is that the format isn't CSV.  Each line has about a dozen fields, and the fields themselves are separated by spaces.  However, some of those fields are strings, which contain space, so I can't just do a find replace for spaces and put the comma in.  One field, the date, is actually formatted like this: `[06/Feb/2018:03:27:37 +0000]`.  This appears to be the only spot where []s are used, so I could find/replace those with "s, but I'm still having trouble importing the document.  It places every row in a single column.

So, to summarize, my goal is to take an input file and break up each row so that the space is the delimiter, but it ignores spaces within quotes.

Comment: replace spaces outside [] with tab characters

Comment: How do I do that without replacing the spaces inside [] as well? It's a large file.

Comment: if you have an editor that can use regex (for example textwrangler or bbedit)  or you are willing to use sed (in this case remember the -E flag) or to write a small filter in any language you know (for example perl or python), you can first change the brackets into "s and then use the regex s/\ (?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)/\t/g (it's not that I am this good with regexes, it's explained here: https://regex101.com/r/sU3fA2/29)

Comment: just out of curiosity, but the file is not fixed length fields (but for the log text), is it?

Comment: @GioValerio Do you mean the number of fields per row? If so, it does appear to be fixed length fields, with fields with no data having a '-' symbol instead. I've never used RegEx but dang does it look like you can get fancy with it.  Thanks for the link / regex.

Comment: @GioValerio Awesome, I was able to write a Python script to replace those spaces with commas.  Made parsing these files wayyy easier.  Now i just need to update this script to handle a directory and iterate over each file so I don't have to stitch them together, but for my purposes now I was able to quickly and easily find the info I needed from these logs.  If you put your comment in an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: yep, Regular Expressions can really be useful. But I prefer to split a problem in parts than to obstinately try to find a single regex that does it all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have an editor that can use regex (for example textwrangler or bbedit)
or you are willing to use sed (in this case remember the -E flag)
or you can write a small filter in any language you know (for example perl or python),
you can first change the brackets into "s and then use the regex:
    s/\ (?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)/\t/g
to convert any space not between quotes into tabs, so that Numbers will import it correctly (it's not that I am this good with regexes, it is explained here: regex101.com/r/sU3fA2/29)